# Access violation Error and FlashPlayer

Tags: flash, delphi, browser, access-violation

I use a `Web-Browser` control on my Delphi application. the Web-Browser control should navigates some HTML pages that contains `Flash(SWF)` files. It is often OK and there is no problem, But sometimes i get this error when my app is running.

> Access violation at address 69864A7A in module 'Flash10q.ocx'. Wrote of address 0A35AB07.

why?

Comment: Do you get the AV when you navigate to the flash page, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

The Flash player tried to write to a part of memory it does not have access to so the operating system prevented it and probably terminated the player.

Could be a bug in the flash player, or a corrupted install (reinstall it) or it could be some failed attempt of the .swf that was loaded to infect your system (could be designed for windows). Or your CPU is bugging up and randomizing it's operations forcing the computer to have a heart attack every couple of minutes once it does that and it has the possibility to create damage (you overclocked the computer). Or...

Try reinstalling Flash. If that doesn't fix it, don't bother to much with it, it's impossible to know exactly what is going on without showing it to somebody really knowledgeable with flash internals, assembly and debugging.

Comment: Thank you so much. and is there a way to handle this error in Delphi?

Comment: This type of error will result in termination of the program since the operating system can not trust it's integrity anymore as it has stepped on the very basic tenant of the OS architecture (don't mess with memory you are not given permission to mess with). So, no, there probably isn't. What has that got to do with flash?

Comment: oh delphi, application, I see. Use a different version of flash or something, it might go away... You can try that thing in the first answer though it might not be a solution to your problem at all.

Comment: whopsie, TWebBrowser is not Chromium... My guess would be for you to try to get ring0 access (driver access) for your program in the OS if possible, it might "go away" or it might blow up spectacular. Zero clue if Delphi is capable of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

Chromium have a sandbox to avoid this, I suggest you to use "Delphi Chromium Embedded" instead.
http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/

Comment: "Use another browser and different control" is no way an answer to the question "why am I getting an access violation". This at best should have been a comment to the original question.

Comment: I am sorry but there is no other valid response to this problem

Comment: Yes, there is. "My car doesn't start. It's a Porsche.". "Ok, buy a Ford." isn't a valid answer.

Comment: you still wrong, a sandbox is actually the only way to protect the browser from external plugin, and as far I know, chrome is the only browser to implement it. do you have a solid argument that is not not based on cars ?

Comment: You're missing the point. The question was about TWebBrowser and Flash, and talking about Chromium is meaningless since it is not TWebBrowser. That's where the car analogy comes from - the solution to a problem with a Porsche isn't solved by buying a Ford. A problem with TWebBrowser isn't instantly solved by switching to something else,

Comment: since the issue has no solution, I honestly think it is reasonable to propose an alternative.